Dynamic setting of function parameter selectivity？
// Firstly, I want to implement setting the parameter selectivity of the current function based on a certain generic parameter type mentioned earlier. I came up with the idea of using parameter sets and tuples.
// When using parameter sets to dynamically set whether parameters are optional, it causes a series of abnormalities.
// Due to the complexity of the actual situation, I have made a simplified example as follows:
interface Options<I> {
  init?: I,
  getInit?: () => I
}

function fun1 <P>(par: P) {
  function fun2 <I, O extends P extends boolean ? [options: Options<I>] : [options?: Options<I>]>(...arg: O) {
    return {
      p: '' as P,
      i: '' as I
    }
  }

  return fun2
}

// The first question: Generic I is always unknown
// The second question is that the type of init and the return value type of getInit are not mutually constrained. I think it's because of the first issue.
const { p, i } = fun1(true)({
  init: "1",
  getInit: () => "1"
})

How to correct abnormal situations, or are there other ways to dynamically set the optional function parameters?

The following content is for the second editing:
When editing the content here, I have already come up with some methods through simple experiments, and I am not sure if there are any other side effects. I am recording this for others to refer to.
The above example lacks the use of the generic parameter O. The following example will use O and be able to correctly determine the actual input content of O.
function fun1<P>(par: P) {
  function fun2<I, O extends Options<I>>(
    ...arg: P extends boolean
        ? [options: Options<I> & O]
        : [options?: Options<I> & O]
  ) {
    return {
      p: '' as P,
      i: '' as I,
      g: '' as unknown as O extends { getInit: () => any } ? true : false
    }
  }

  return fun2
}

const { p, i, g } = fun1(true)({
  init: "1",
  getInit: () => "1"
})
// p boolean
// i string
// g true


You don't need the generic parameter O for anything here. If you don't reference a generic type anywhere expect it's inference site, then you don't need it to be generic.
This is identical:
function fun1<P>(par: P) {
  function fun2<I>(
    ...arg:
      P extends boolean
        ? [options: Options<I>]
        : [options?: Options<I>]
  ) {
    return {
      p: '' as P,
      i: '' as I
    }
  }

  return fun2
}

And with that that I can be inferred easily, and correctly:
const { p, i } = fun1(true)({
  init: "1",
  getInit: () => "1"
})

i // type: string

And you you do need the I generic because you use it in the return type.
See playground

As for why, well, I'm not sure I can describe that. Just know that the minimizing the number of generic parameters, especially when they depend on each other, generally makes it less likely that the type checker will get confused.

That's true, but I omitted the use of the generic parameter O in the fun2 method. However, your answer also gave me some inspiration, thank you very much!
